# Is slideDown() in jQuery not applicable to body and html elements?

Tags: jquery, html, css

When I apply slideDown to the body element, it just kinda "pops" onto the screen. I tried to set the slideDown speed (e.g slideDown(8000)) but it doesn't work. Is slideDown just not applicable to the body and html element? And yes I had set the display to none in CSS before trying this

Comment: Doesn't look like it.

Comment: I've created a [**demo page**](http://jsbin.com/dufekoluka/edit?html,css,js,output) showing the limitations -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot apply SlideDown() to body or html tags but you can just wrap all your content inside a div and slide that down.

CSS

```
#bodyContent {
   display:none;
   height: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="bodyContent">
    //your page/code
</div>
```

JQuery

```
   $('#bodyContent').slideDown();
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark my answer as Accepted Answer appropriately.